# How to add a dll file into reference of Visual Studio properly?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll

I know people normally add a dll file into the reference of Visual Studio very easily as follow:

```
1) Right Click on Reference
2) Choose Add Reference
3) Browse and choose dll file
```

However, with this approach, VS seems to store the absolute path, pointing to my dll file, rather than copy dll file into VS's project memory.

What if I remove the dll file from the hard driver? or what if I want to deploy the project on another computer?

Sorry, I am quite new to .Net

Comment: It stores the relative path so for developers it is just a matter of ensuring that the DLLs are in source control in the right location. There is no such thing as "VS's project memory" as far as I am aware.

Comment: What have you tried? It might be worth looking at nuget and how it works (it stores a reference to a project and goes and gets a copy from the interweb if it's missing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in your question, this is the way you reference a class library or any other DLL-like reference.

Once compiled, your project copies its dependencies into its `bin` folder where you can find the referenced DLLs.

If you can't find the referenced DLL, set its `Copy Local` property to `true`.

Another way around is to set your [**Reference Paths**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8y13ka7c(v=vs.90).aspx). This will force, on compile-time, your project to update itself with DLLs from the specified reference paths.

The best practice was to create a `Shared` folder where all referenced libraries were in, so that you could write your reference paths once and for all per project.

Technologies being so great and vast on improvements, there's now [**NuGet Package Manager**](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c).

**What is NuGet?**

> *A collection of tools to automate the process of downloading, installing, upgrading, configuring, and removing packages from a VS Project.*

**How to use NuGet?**

You may install it from within Visual Studio if it is not already installed, through the [**Extension Manager**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293638.aspx).

Otherwise, please visit the [**NuGet CodePlex Home Page**](https://nuget.codeplex.com/).

Here's how [**Finding and Installing a NuGet Package Using the Package Manager Console**](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console) has never been easier! =)

So when you open up an existing project, NuGet manages to get all the dependencies for you without any more effort from you. This should solve your concerns.